# Update Numpy, Scipy without disturbing the rest of ubuntu system

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, ubuntu-16.04

I need to use a newer version of Scipy with python3. 
I tried upgrading with pip3 with the following command
`pip3 install --upgrade scipy --user`

Pip3 reports that it successfully installed scipy-1.3.1 (it also says that it skipped numpy upgrade)

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/0e/371881e018d...
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/locallib/python3.5/dist-packages (from scipy) (1.17.0)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.3.1
```

Now, when I import scipy it is the older version (0.17.0)

```
>>> print(scipy.__version__)
0.17.0
```

I tried to reinstall scipy (this time with sudo)
`sudo pip3 install --upgrade scipy`
But pip3 complains that it cannot uninstall older scipy because it is a `distutil` package.

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/0e/371881e018d...   
    100% |⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜| 25.1MB 895kB/s  
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/locallib/python3.5/dist-packages (from scipy) (1.17.0)
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.17.0
Cannot uninstall 'scipy'. It is a distutil installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it whicch would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I tried to remove the distutil package using **synaptic** package manager. However, in order to uninstall **synaptic** is asking me to remove other packages that depend on scipy.
[image]

One of those packages **ubuntu-mate-desktop** is a part of my ubuntu system and I dont want to fiddle with it.

Kindly suggest me how do I install (upgrade) scipy and numpy without breaking system packages.

Comment: Don't use your system Python for these things!

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output!

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual environment `virtualenv`.

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Is there a solution to the original problem?

Comment: This is the recommended solution (modulo using virtualenv or venv), not a workaround.

Comment: I have used virtual env in the past and it's an overhead. I desire one set of packages. That way I don't have to do `venv activate` and what packages are in which environment etc.. I thank you for your answer but it is not what I am looking for.